# Flexdashboard DT datatable not filling panel height

Tags: r, dt, flexdashboard

I have tried everything, but am stumped trying to get a DT datatable to fill the panel of a flexdashboard. It employs a scroller, but I cannot find any way to force the table to be the full height of the panel. In the image linked below, it is the table on the right that causes problems and seems to be related to the fact that it is in a loop (inputting a table per tab). When I exclude the loop and just do one table, it will fill the panel. I can play about with some scroller parameters to make it larger, but then it will not be full panel on every screen. I just want some way to make it auto-fill the tabbed panel size each time. Thanks in advance for your help.

[flex image - see right panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gjw3.png)

````
```
## XXX Detailed Reports {.tabset}
``` {r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results="asis"} 
for (i in 1:length(c_list)){
  cty=c("XXX","FFF","GGG","TTT","RRR","PPP","LLL","WWW","EEE")
  cat("### ", cty[i], "\n")
  cat("#### ",cty[i],paste("Week ",floor(yday(as.Date(format(Sys.Date() - wday(Sys.Date() + 1), "%d %B %Y"),"%d %B %Y"))/7)+1,sep="")," Other Text here", "\n")

  x = data.frame(c_list[i]) %>% mutate_if(is.character, function(x) {Encoding(x) <- 'latin1'; return(x)}) # remove strange sysmbols
  
  tb=x %>%
  DT::datatable(
    extensions = c("Buttons", "Responsive", "Scroller", "RowGroup"), 
    options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', 
                   buttons = c('excel', "csv"),
                   rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 0),
                   deferRender = TRUE,
                   #scrollY = 800,
                   #scroller = TRUE,
                   scrollCollapse = FALSE,
                   columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0))),
                   paging=FALSE,
                   searching=FALSE,
                   info=FALSE),
    selection = 'none',
    rownames=F) %>%
  formatStyle(columns = colnames(.$x$data), `font-size` = "12px")
  
  print(htmltools::tagList(tb))
  #cat("\n")
}
```
````